# Which semisimple elements of a semisimple Lie algebra belong to some $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional, semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$. I would like to know which semisimple elements of $\mathfrak g$ belong to some subalgebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \subseteq \mathfrak g$.

Comment: Since the union of Cartan subalgebras is the set of semisimple elements, your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314046/does-semisimple-element-of-a-semisimple-complex-lie-algebra-belong-to-some-carta) might me relevant, too?

Comment: I do see a connection, and the fact that I asked both questions is by no means an accident. Nevertheless I don't see if the answer to the previous question solves this one.

Answer (score 4):

Not all. If $x$ is semisimple and contained in a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, then since every semisimple element of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is regular, $x$ is proportional to a standard Cartan element $h$. As $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation, the eigenvalues of $ad(h)$ are integers, and hence the eigenvalues of $ad(x)$ are integer multiples of some $c \in \mathbb C$. This is not true of all semisimple elements.

The converse seems to follow from the proof of the Jacobson-Morozov theorem: if the eigenvalues of semisimple $ad(x)$ are integer multiples of some $c \in \mathbb C$, then $x$ is contained in an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple. [These notes I found by googling "Jacobson-Morozov"](http://school-tlag2017.math.cnrs.fr/Docs/exos_Losev.pdf) contain the necessary steps of the proof in Section 3.